# run pandas udf on single batch

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

according to the docs pandas UDF's work the following way:

> The Python function should take a pandas Series as an input and return
> a pandas Series of the same length, and you should specify these in
> the Python type hints. Spark runs a pandas UDF by splitting columns
> into batches, calling the function for each batch as a subset of the
> data, then concatenating the results.

Is it possible to run the pandas UDF only on a single batch? I saw the option `spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch`, but since its default to 10'000 and my dataset that is much smaller still runs in batches.

Comment: Did you mean partitions? In my experience, Pyspark splits your data into partitions then apply UDF or Pandas UDF on each partitions at a time. So you can try `.repartition(1)` before calling your UDF